# Is there a way in Python to translate a hexidecimal representation of a fixed point number to the decimal representation of a fixed point number?

Tags: python, decimal, fixed-point, bit-representation

I am aware of [numfi](https://pypi.org/project/numfi/), which allows me to represent a decimal fixed point as a hexidecimal. For example:

```
import numfi
y = numfi(0.5378, 1, 32, 30)
y.hex

array(['226B50B1'], dtype='<U8')
```

However, lets say I only have the value `0x226B50B1` and know that the representation is Q1.30, but don't know what decimal value that is. Is there a method that allows me to see the equivalent decimal representation of 0.5378? If not in numfi, then any other method in Python?

For example:

```
y = numfi(0x226B50B1, 1, 32, 30)
```

Does not do what I want.

Comment: `0x226B50B1 / 2**30` produces 0.5378000000491738.

Comment: Oh, wow, that was obvious. Thanks.